# Qt web GUI alternatives for Python

Tags: python, user-interface, visual-web-gui

Are there frameworks for making GUI for web pages like Qt for desktop applications? Preferably with graphical form designer.
I need framework supporting tabs, trees, splitters, etc.

Comment: I have the same question. It seems there is a new tool: Qt for WebAssembly (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/wasm.html) but will this work for python ?